# Javers - java.lang.ClassCastException: org.javers.core.diff.changetype.ValueChange cannot be cast to org.javers.core.diff.changetype.map.MapChange

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

I am getting below error working on Spring Boot Javers example.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringbootJaVersApplication.main(SpringbootJaVersApplication.java:37) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.javers.core.diff.changetype.ValueChange cannot be cast to org.javers.core.diff.changetype.map.MapChange
    at com.example.SpringbootJaVersApplication.withJavers(SpringbootJaVersApplication.java:118) [classes/:na]
    at com.example.SpringbootJaVersApplication.run(SpringbootJaVersApplication.java:49) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

**Code:**

```
List<Change> snapshots = javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(c.getId(), Car.class).build());
for (Change ch : snapshots) {
    if(ch instanceof ValueChange) {
        System.out.println("Change is an instance of value change...");
        ValueChange vc = (ValueChange) ch;
        System.out.println(vc.getPropertyName());
        System.out.println(vc.getAffectedGlobalId());
        System.out.println(vc.getLeft()+"  "+vc.getRight());
    }

    if(ch instanceof PropertyChange) {
        PropertyChange pc = (PropertyChange)ch;
        System.out.println(pc.getPropertyName());
        System.out.println(pc.getAffectedGlobalId());

        MapChange mc = (MapChange)pc;
        System.out.println(mc.getPropertyName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the typecast or the line after it that merely repeats what has gone before. Clearly the typecast needs to be inside another `if (ch instanceof ...)` test block.

Comment: You might want to improve the title of the question to attract more viewers

Comment: @ user207421- Can you guide me how to use the MapChange from change object?

Comment: The error message already tells you that you can't.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says is all, you can't cast from this `PropertyChange` object to `MapChange`, because `MapChange` is a subclass of `PropertyChange`, and this object isn't. There are many other subclasses, like `ValueChange`:

[image]

Comment: What is the best way to send history of property changes to UI? I was thinking to create Map of all and send, but it doesn't seem working

Comment: @PAA That's because you aren't doing it. You aren't *creating* a map at all. You are trying to cast an existing *value* change *event* into a *map* change event, which it isn't. Try doing exactly what you said in your comment.

Comment: @Bartek - Are you thinking to have functionality to develop Map (Javers API) to support Map, which will store all history of data for same key?

Answer (score -1):

"ValueChange cannot be cast to MapChange"

I think if you try to cast a PropertyChange to MapChange you will have the same issue.

Are PropertyChange and ValueChange childs of the abstract class MapChange?

Can you show here the code of the 3 classes?

Comment: He *is* casting a `PropertyChange` to a `MapChange` and this *is* the issue.

Comment: Brilliant, Mr. Wozniak, but in OOP there are something called **polimorphism**, and you can have a superclass and many subclasses. Thats what I'm understanding from the code, and that's what im asking.

Comment: The OP's code shows clearly that `(ch instanceof PropertyChange)` must have been true, and that the offending typecast is between `PropertyChange pc` and `MapChange`. Otherwise the offending typecast could not have been executed. Your point?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.javers.core.diff.changetype.ValueChange cannot be cast to org.javers.core.diff.changetype.map.MapChange

Comment: Read the code. He has (1) `if (ch instanceof PropertyChange)`; (2) `PropertyChange pc = (PropertyChange)ch;`; and then (3) `MapChange mc = (MapChange)pc;`. The latter constitutes casting a `PropertyChange` to `MapChange`. He is already doing it, and he is already having the issue.